Using custom font inside C#
In my program, I use the following function to set the custom font.
And the Function runs correctly.
public void SetFontControls()
{
    PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

    var fontLength = Properties.Resources.Titr.Length;
    var fontData = Properties.Resources.Titr;
    var data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
    Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, data, fontLength);
    pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);

    //pfc.AddFontFile(@"C:\font\.ttf");

    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 12);
    }
}

The problem is that some fonts work correctly, some don't!
I don't know what the reason is.
Both fonts are in .ttf format.
One works (Titr.ttf)
The second one is not set.(Titr2.ttf)
It is surprising that if I call the font statically and from outside the program, the font is applied.
 //pfc.AddFontFile(@"C:\font\Titr2.ttf");

I really don't know what the problem is.
File font is link below
First Font
Second Font

You clearly did not read the answer I suggested in your other question. If you had read it, you would have known what the problem is. 1) You must declare the PFC as class field. 2) You should not call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data); The PFC needs data alive as long as the font is used. 3) Dispose of the PFC instance when you close the Form....etc. Please read the referred answer again. Read it carefully this time.

AddFontFile() registers the Font with GDI, calling AddFontResourceEx(), AddMemoryFont() doesn't -- Your PrivateFontCollection should be retained as a Field, and you should not call FreeCoTaskMem()
